Error java.lang.NullPointerException client home oracle 21c
tengo un problema al instalar el cliente home de oracle 21c en mi maquina. El error que me aparece cuando llega al momento de la instalación es "java.lang.NullPointerException".
Tengo Java 8 instalado y mi sistema operativo es Windows

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias!!

Lo mejor sería que les preguntes al soporte técnico de oracle. Nosotros no sabemos cómo funciona internamente, ese error no dice absolutamente nada de lo que puede haber pasado... Busca algún tipo de log, que seguro que algún log ha generado, y con eso seguro que ellos podrán ayudarte. A lo mejor incluso podrías encontrar ayuda aquí (CON EL LOG). Tal cual está la pregunta, es imposible saber qué pasa
